# ScrollToRow - How to get last rows to scroll to top of screen?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath, scroll-position

I'm using `tableView.scrollToRow` inside of the `didSelectRowAt` method so that whenever a row is selected, the view automatically scrolls the next row to the top of the screen. I got it working fine, except I'm not sure how to deal with the last few rows when there's enough room in the screen to fit everything.

In the example below, clicking on Step 5 onwards displays the scenario I'm describing.

[image: Example]

Here is my relevant code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let topInstruction = arrayOne[currentArrayOneIndex!].instructions![topInstructionIndex]
        print(topInstructionIndex)
        print(arrayOne[currentArrayOneIndex!].instructions!.count)
        
        // Check if it is the last instruction
        if topInstructionIndex < arrayOne[currentArrayOneIndex!].instructions!.count {
            
            // Change cell colour to green
            let tappedInstruction = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
            tappedInstruction?.contentView.backgroundColor =  #colorLiteral(red: 0.3411764801, green: 0.6235294342, blue: 0.1686274558, alpha: 1)
            
            topInstructionIndex += 1
            
            // Scroll to the next instruction
            let nextInstruction = IndexPath(row: topInstructionIndex, section: 0)
            tableView.scrollToRow(at: nextInstruction, at: UITableView.ScrollPosition.top, animated: true)
            return
            
        }
        else {
            // Finish the instructions
            print("This is the last instruction.")
            return
        }

    }
```

Is there anything I can add to the `didSelectRowAt` (or elsewhere) to scroll the last rows to the top, even when everything fits on screen?

Comment: use contentInsets(bottom = tableview.bound.height)

Comment: you can consider setting `contentInsets` or adding an empty cell to then bottom of tableview.

Comment: Thank you @SPatel and @congnd! That was exactly right. Posting the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following code to the `cellForRowAt` method did the trick.

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 500, right: 0)
```

Thank you to [@SPatel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6630644/spatel) and @congnd for the comments that led to this answer.